# Поиск слов в тексте на python

Tags: python, инспекция-кода

Почему такие мессенджеры как Telegram or WatsApp не добавят функцию по поиску слов в тексте? Я считаю это порой бывает весьма полезно найти слово. Поэтому я хочу вам представить код на python который ищет два слова с расстоянием не больше указанного.

```
    import re
text = {
    1 : 'Разнообразный и богатый опыт дальнейшее развитие различных форм деятельности в значительной степени обуславливает создание модели развития',
    2 : 'Соображения высшего порядка а также повышение уровня гражданского сознания играет важную роль в формировании новых предложений',
    3 : 'Равным образом выбранный нами инновационный путь требует от нас системного анализа системы масштабного изменения ряда параметров',
    4 : 'С другой стороны социально-экономическое развитие требует от нас анализа экономической целесообразности принимаемых решений',
    5 : 'Практический опыт показывает что повышение уровня гражданского сознания представляет собой интересный эксперимент проверки экономической целесообразности принимаемых решений', 
    6 : 'Таким образом консультация с профессионалами из IT требует определения и уточнения направлений прогрессивного развития.',
    7 : 'Соображения высшего порядка а также сложившаяся структура организации'
}

#new version
#----------------------------------------------VARS-----------------------------------------------
num = 0
i = 0
cc = 0
sl = '' 
rez_one = 0 
rez_two = 0
lent_one = 0 
lent_two = 0
lent_g = 0
#----------------------------------------------VARS-------------------------------------------------
first_w = input('Введите первое слово: ')
second_w = input('Введите второе слово: ')
rast_s = input('Введите максимальное расстояние между словами: ')
print('Режимы: 1 - первое слово в тексте раньше второго, 2 - второе раньше, 3 - без разницы')
mode = input('Введите режим: ')
rast_s = int(rast_s)
mode = int(mode) 
#----------------------------------------------VARS-------------------------------------------------
for key in text:
    num = num + 1
    sl = text[num].split()
    cc = len(sl)
    rez_one = 0
    rez_two = 0
    i = 0
    lent_g = 0
    while i < cc:
        if first_w == sl[i]:
            rez_one = sl[i]
            lent_one = i
        elif second_w == sl[i]:
            rez_two = sl[i]
            lent_two = i
        else:
            pass
        i = i + 1
    if mode == 1:    
        lent_g = lent_two - lent_one - 1
    elif mode == 2:
        lent_g = lent_one - lent_two - 1 
    elif mode == 3:
        if lent_two > lent_one:
            lent_g = lent_two - lent_one - 1
        elif lent_one > lent_two:
            lent_g = lent_one - lent_two - 1
        else:
            pass
    else:
        pass
    if rez_one != 0 and rez_two != 0 and lent_g <= rast_s and lent_g >= 0:
        print('Вот номер искомого предложения:', num)
    else:
        print('Не найдено')
```

P.S все предложения/советы/примечания принимаются, давайте вместе сделаем этот код лучше!

Comment: На Stack Overflow на русском вопросы принято задавать только на русском языке. Пожалуйста, переведите ваш вопрос на русский язык или воспользуйтесь Stack Overflow на английском.

Comment: 1) А причем тут мессенджеры? 2) В них доступен поиск по истории 3) Зачем такой поиск нужен? Мне непонятен смысл поиска между двумя словами :)

Comment: Чтоб находить фразы, по двум словам это удобно, так же как по мне это применимо для различных документов

Comment: Какое отношение это имеет к вацапу и телеграму?